# Low Variables & Grid outputting raw code

Tags: low-variables, grid, template-scripting

I'm working with the grid fieldtype for the first time and attempting to build out a home page slider the same way I would typically do with matrix and low variables.

I have triple checked cell names (and copy/pasted to template code) yet the slider is not displaying the images as expected. My code is here:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv-home-slider"}
  <img src="{slide}" alt="{caption}"/>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

But on the front end it outputs the following.

```
<img src="{slide}" alt="{caption}" >

<img src="{slide}" alt="{caption}" >
```

I've tried setting this variable to early parsing which as expected didn't change a thing. Have attached a screenshot of the grid settings in Low Variables.

[image]

Comment: I don't why it would matter, but what happens if you use `{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv-home-slider" multiple="yes"}` tag pair instead?

Comment: The `multiple="yes"` parameter only applies to variable types that have Options set in its settings, like Checkbox Group and Select variable types. Also, Sean, if you're using the Tag syntax for a variable, early parsing is irrelevant, and it's actually better to leave it disabled.

Comment: Hat tip to anyone reading this in the future. I was getting the following error Fatal error: Call to a member function parse_type() on a non-object in /home/hagwil/public_html/hvcsys/expressionengine/fieldtypes/textarea/ft.textarea.php on line 73 due to one of my cells being a textarea. Once I changed it to text input all was good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables inside the field [need to be prefixed](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#variables) with the Grid variable name, like this:

```
{lv-home-slider:slide}
{lv-home-slider:caption}
```

Comment: oh didn't know that. How inefficient.

Comment: Well, it does avoid variable name conflicts.